# wpdb get posts by taxonomy SQL

Tags: query, wpdb, sql

I need a list of posts of a specific post_type plus the name of a custom taxonomy term.

This is what I got so far

```
SELECT p.post_name,t.name as clientName 
FROM $wpdb->posts AS p, $wpdb->terms AS t
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr ON ('p.ID' = tr.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms AS t2 ON (t2.term_id = tt.term_id)
WHERE   p.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND p.post_type = 'portfolio'
    AND tt.taxonomy = 'clients' 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

What´s the problem?
I´m getting too many results, I get the right posts, but several times with every client.
I guess thats because I use $wpdb->terms as t AND as t2?
But when I try to use it as t both times I get the error

```
Not unique table/alias: 't'
```

Who can help?

Comment: Use `WP_Query`. Cannot see why you need to run a custom SQL query

Comment: @Pieter: Hmm ok, how would that look like? Would it be possible with WP_Query to filter by two taxonomies as well? As I need to filter for "language" taxonomy created by the  Polylang Plugin

Comment: Have you read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: Yeah thanks, but that won´t give me the name of the taxonomy in one go, right? I´d have to make a wp_get_post_terms() for each post again, which sums up to alot of queries I guess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry guys, I just found the solution:

```
SELECT p.post_name, t.name as clientName 
FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr ON ( p.ID = tr.object_id)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS t ON (t.term_id = tt.term_id)
WHERE   p.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND p.post_type = 'portfolio'
    AND tt.taxonomy = 'clients' 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

I just don't have to define an alias for `$wpdb->terms` in `FROM` clause.

Comment: Need to remove the single quotes from around `p.ID`